# How can I force the Average function to include null values?

Tags: c#

I wrote the following inside my asp.net mvc application:

```
double d = visits.Average(d=> d.amount);
```

But the above code ingores any object that is Null, returning an unrealistic result in my case. How can I force the Average function to calculate the average as :

```
double d = visits.Sum(d=> d.amount)/visit.Count();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So you want `null` values to be interpreted as 0?

```
double d = visits.Average(d => d.amount ?? 0);
```